# node express body-parser for application/logplex-1

Tags: node.js, parsing, heroku, express, body-parser

I am using node express to process POST requests of [heroku logging data](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains) with body data that is in the `application/logplex-1` format (apparently [syslog formatted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6)).

In particular, I am using the [body-parser module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) as middleware to parse the POST body.

It works OK to specify `app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'application/logplex-1' }))` to force `body-parser` to parse the body as text, but the text is just a big block of space-separated information without much structure other than that.  Therefore I need to parse the body data further to find and extract what I want.

This is OK, but I'm wondering if there is, perhaps, a better way of parsing the `logplex-1` body more directly into something more structured and easier to work with, like JSON.  I'm not familiar with `logplex-1` or the syslog format, and whether it does indeed have anything more useful structure/metadata in it than is apparent from the text block I'm currently getting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with logplex or Heroku, but this seems to be working:

```
var syslogParser = require('glossy').Parse;
var express      = require('express');
var app          = express();
var server       = app.listen(3012);

// Express allows arrays-of-middleware to act as a "single" middleware.
var logplexMiddleware = [
  // First, read the message body into `req.body`, making sure it only
  // accepts logplex "documents".
  require('body-parser').text({ type: 'application/logplex-1' }),
  // Next, split `req.body` into separate lines and parse each one using
  // the `glossy` syslog parser.
  function(req, res, next) {
    req.body = (req.body || '').split(/\r*\n/).filter(function(line) {
      // Make sure we only parse lines that aren't empty.
      return line.length !== 0;
    }).map(function(line) {
      // glossy doesn't like octet counts to be prepended to the log lines,
      // so remove those.
      return syslogParser.parse(line.replace(/^\d+\s+/, ''));
    });
    next();
  }
];

// Example endpoint:
app.post('/', logplexMiddleware, function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

It uses [`glossy`](https://github.com/squeeks/glossy) to parse the syslog messages into Javascript objects.

If the amount of data being posted is considerable (>hundreds of K's), it might be better to implement a streaming solution as the code above will first read the entire message body into memory.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep, really useful answer, both in respect of my specific issue and more generally as to how to create custom middleware.  I've tried it with the log messages being received from heroku, and am finding that the `glossy` syslogParser is just producing a json object with a single `originalMessage` element in it, which is just the entire log text block.  So in this specific case it seems that there is no benefit to using `glossy`, unless perhaps there is a way to tell it about the particular syslog message format (I cannot see how).

Comment: @drmrbrewer hmm I think that Heroku may not send distinct log _lines_. Can you create a gist with some data so I can take a look at what it's sending?

Comment: well this an example (suitably redacted) of originalMessage: `444 <158>1 2015-08-20T12:31:02.055232+00:00 host heroku router - at=info method=GET path="/xxx/yyy" host=zzz.herokuapp.com request_id=xxx fwd="0.000.000.00" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=494`

Comment: @drmrbrewer I edited my answer to remove the numerical prefix (which is a byte count), but it sounds as if the logs aren't separated by newline (instead, the byte count should be used to determine how long each log line is). In which case the `.split()` won't work either. Can you see distinct newlines in the data that's being sent, or do the log records look concatenated?

Comment: removing the numerical prefix helped a *lot*.  At least, this seems to allow glossy to extract some of the "housekeeping" information like dates, app, etc into specific json elements, with a "message" element containing a block of text that I'll probably just have to split up manually to get at what I need.  But it's helpful to have the housekeeping stuff already parsed out.  I think there aren't any newlines... just a concatenated block of text for each log entry -- would that affect your code snippet?

Comment: @drmrbrewer yeah, it would mean that you need to use the byte count prefixes to split the lines manually.

Comment: OK thanks @robertklep.  Referring to the example data I gave above, the "message" element now contains everything from `at=info` onwards, with the stuff before that parsed out into json elements by `glossy`

Comment: @drmrbrewer right, that will require some additional parsing (it's just the _message_ part of a syslog document, which AFAIK can contain just about anything).